# Simple PHP login won't connect to DB

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

Below is the code for a member to login and connect to database. I have set up the database, the database owner user and password, the database "members" table, and a database member user. The first bit of code is just the html form to log in [it is the index file], the second is the PHP file [checklogin.php] that is supposed to connect said user to the database. The problem is that whatever is typed into html form will let the user to the next page saying "hey, user, you are signed in" even if that user is not in the members table. I have a feeling they are not REALLY connecting at all, it's just echoing that out. - All db info is keyed out with ++++++

```
    <html>
    <form action='checklogin.php' method='POST'
    <strong>username:</strong><br />
    <input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"><br />
    <strong>password:</strong><br />
    <input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"><br />
    <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Login">
    </form>
    </html> 

    <?php
    $host="localhost"; 
    $username="++++++"; 
    $password="++++++"; 
    $db_name="++++++"; 
    $tbl_name="members"; 

    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
    $myusername=$_POST['myusername'];
    $mypassword=$_POST['mypassword'];
    echo "hey, " . $myusername . ", you are correctly signed in."
    ?>
```

Thank you. I am going to add elements of security after I get this going. It is going to eventually log the user in and have have them go right to their profile.

Comment: You aren't performing any database queries. Your code is always doing the same thing, regardless of the user input. Databases aren't magic, you still have to write actual code!

Comment: Did you query the database, or just connected? ;P

Comment: Q: Can you connect to that database in mysql with that username and password from the command line (e.g. "mysql -uxyz -pabc mydb")? And did you realize you're not using any database tables or either of your POST variables?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mysql_connect()` returns a connection resource that you need to pass to a call to `mysql_query()`, along with a SQL query to determine if the credentials match a user in the database.

```
$con = mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db_name)
```

Your query needs to check the DB to see if `$myusername` exists, and that the password for `$myusername` equals `$mypassword`.  You mentioned the table name was members.

```
$user = mysql_query("select password from members where username = '" . 
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']) . "'", $con);

if(mysql_num_rows($user) == 0) {
    // Username not found
}

$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
if($_POST['password'] != $user['password']) {
    // Password does not match
}
```

The actual query depends on the schema of your database.

Answer (score 3):

Well you're not executing any queries or doing any sort of validation, so it's obviously just going to print that statement no matter what.  I think you want something like this (but it highly depends on your table structure)

```
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername']);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['mypassword']);
$query = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_name where username=$myusername AND password=$mypassword";
$result = mysql_query($query);
$user = mysql_fetch_array($result);
if ($user) {
  echo "hey, " . $myusername . ", you are correctly signed in."
} else {
  echo "Not signed in."
}
```

This will check the members table to see if a user with that name/password is in the table.

Also notice I'm using `mysql_real_escape_string` on the post variables, which will help protect against SQL injection attacks.

Comment: <?php
$server="localhost"; 
$dbuser="++++++"; 
$dbpass="++++++"; 
$db_name="++++++"; 
$tbl_name="members"; 

mysql_connect($server, $dbuser, $dbpass);
mysql_select_db($db_name)


$user = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['myusername'])

if(mysql_num_rows($user) == 0) {
    // Username not found
}

$user = mysql_fetch_assoc($user);
if($_POST['password'] != $user['password']) {
    // Password does not match
}

?>

Hi all, thanks for all of the help. I kind of joined what was commented here, and I'm getting a T_VARIBLE error on line 12

Comment: Can you please add the code into your question, as it's hard to read there, but it still doesn't look like you're executing any queries.

Answer (score 0):

You connected Only to the database using `mysql_connect()`.
This looks good.
`mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");  mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");`

But you need to validate the user and display the username.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['username']));
$password=md5(mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($_POST['password'])));
$query="select * from login1 where username='$username' AND password='$password'";
$result=mysql_query($query);
if(mysql_num_rows($result)!=1)
{
//If the username or password wrong 
}
else
{
//Username and password correct
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo "hey, " . $row['username'] . ", you are correctly signed in."
}
```

[Take a look this example.](http://blogforsite.blogspot.in/2012/05/simple-login-using-php-mysql.html)